# Expectation expression with Matrix Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra

So yeah, i am trying to work some things out in linear algrebra so, i have this expression: $\mathbb{E}[(Kx_i +e)(Kx_i +e)^{T}]$ And below is my attempt to expand it (from right-to-left):
$\mathbb{E}[(Kx_i +e)(Kx_i +e)^{T}] = $
$\mathbb{E}[(e^{T}e + e^{T}Kx_i +x_i^{T}K^{T}Kx_i +x_i^{T}K^{T}e)]$

My question is: Can this $x_i^{T}K^{T}Kx_i$ be written differently? I basically read from matrix cookbook. That term, if I instead tried to expand the given expression from left to right, it would become $Kx_ix_i^{T}K^{T}$ But these two expressions are not equivalent. What am i missing there? (btw ignore the expectation symbol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that matrix multiplication is **not commutative**.  Thus, the correct rule is
$$
(A + B)(C + D) = A(C + D) + B(C + D) = \\
AC + AD + BC + BD
$$
This will generally be something distinct from 
$$
CA + DA + CB + DB
$$
which is what you got with your "right-to-left" expansion.